# Can't library a package when it's already installed in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm fairly new to using R on Mac. I'm having problems in librarying the "weights" package. The installation of this package seems fine:

```
> install.packages("weights")

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/weights_1.0.4.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 176223 bytes (172 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 172 KB

The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/wc/c9pfhbyx3x3b0vxkf89zwnjw0000gp/T//RtmpyYNhQv/downloaded_packages
```

But when I tried to library this package (to use the wpct() function within), it showed:

```
> library(weights)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘weights’:
 object ‘local_preserve_seed’ is not exported by 'namespace:withr'
```

I have no idea what that means. I can't use any functions or get help on the functions contained in the package, while the package seems to be correctly installed. This is so far the only package I try to use that shows this problem. After removing, reinstalling and updating the packages for several rounds, the problem remains. Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling the package immediately after install in the same terminal you installed from? This is perhaps simply `voodoo`, but some packages seem to need to 'settle in', so maybe try closing out the current terminal session and loading `library(weights)` in the fresh terminal session...

Comment: Maybe you have an older version of `withr`. Try updating it with `install.packages("withr")` Then try `library(weights)`

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the reply! I restarted the Rstudio several times and cleared the environment before trying to library the "weights" package (without installing the package all over again), but still every time I get that same error.

Comment: Thanks, MrFlick! Yes, that solved my problem. I installed the "withr" and then the "weights" started to function. Wasn't aware "withr" is actually a package as well...Much appreciated!

Comment: I'd go further than @MrFlick's suggestion:  run `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` to make sure all of your packages are up to date, and avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: @user2554330 Extremely helpful. Will keep that in mind all the time. Thanks!